# Convert UTC to Eastern Prevailing Time (EDT or EST)

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

Can someone tell me how I can convert a UTC date in JodaTime to Eastern Prevailing Time (which    is EST or EDT depending on the time of year?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [withZone()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) to convert a Joda-Time object to a different time-zone.

Comment: Thanks, for this particular case, I used DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");

Comment: The original question was asking if there's a way using JodaTime API to define a date object that will automatically switch to and from Eastern standard and Easter daylight savings time w/o having to modify the code again. I believe answer provided by Bojan Petkovic better addresses the question

Answer (score 3):

Joda takes care of it by itself.  There is a slight difference between using the TimeZone and the Locale of a place.

Take a look at the following examples.

**Using Locale:**

Using @BillMan's suggestion setting DateTimeZone to a locale will actually change the time zone.

```
System.out.println("Winter " + DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).parse("2015-12-01T12:00:00").toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")).toString());
System.out.println("Summer " + DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).parse("2015-05-01T12:00:00").toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")).toString());
```

Returned:

```
Winter 2015-12-01T12:00:00.000-05:00
Summer 2015-05-01T12:00:00.000-04:00
```

**Using TimeZone:**

Note that both times are set to 12:00:00, and the result in Summer got moved by an hour, (but the offset stayed the same)

```
System.out.println("Winter " + DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).parse("2015-12-01T12:00:00").toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("EST")).toString());
System.out.println("Summer " + DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).parse("2015-05-01T12:00:00").toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("EST")).toString());
```

Returned:

```
 Winter 2015-12-01T12:00:00.000-05:00
 Summer 2015-05-01T11:00:00.000-05:00
```

Comment: EDT != EST. On the east coast of America, the prevailing time changes between EDT and EST and vice versa. The result of this is that you skip an hour when moving forward, and have two 1:00 AM when you move back.

Comment: there is no EDT timezone in Joda.  
EST does take into account the difference in daylight saving time.

Comment: EST is a constant -05:00 behind UTC. If you can provide evidence it's not, I'll gladly accept that. See http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est

Comment: @BillMan  Good Point.  It is constant -05:00, but the actual time does get properly switched so it does take into account the daylight saving time.   

Updated the answer to take it into account.